# How do I use libcurl to log into this website? (C++)

Tags: c++, curl, authentication, web, libcurl

I want to make a C++ program to fill in an HTML webform with login credentials (which I currently hardcode into the username and password fields) and then submit the webform and get to the next HTML page.

With the code below, it keeps getting stuck on the logon page and not moving forward. In the console, I keep getting the HTML source code of the logon page instead of the page that comes after I login.

Can someone guide me step-by-step?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
    CURL * myHandle = curl_easy_init ( );

    // Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

    // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "website login page URL here");
    curl_easy_perform( myHandle );

    // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "website login page URL here");
    // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
    char *data="ctl00$LoginTextBox=USERNAME&ctl00$PasswordTextbox=PASSWORD&ctl00$LogInButton=Sign in&ctl00$HiddenValue=Initial Value";
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
    curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
    return 0;
}
```

This is the HTML webform I am dealing with:

```
<div id="loginForm">
    <div id="loginInput">
        <label for="ctl00_LoginTextBox" id="ctl00_LoginLabel">Name/Badge</label>
        <input name="ctl00$LoginTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_LoginTextBox" class="PopupInput" />
    </div>
    <div id="passwordInput">
        <label for="ctl00_PasswordTextbox" id="ctl00_PasswordLabel">Password</label>
        <input name="ctl00$PasswordTextbox" type="password" id="ctl00_PasswordTextbox" class="PopupInput" />        
    </div>
    <div id="equipmentbox">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="ctl00_LoginButtons">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$LogInButton" value="Sign in" id="ctl00_LogInButton" class="btn" />
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$SwitchLoginScreenModeBT" value="Change Password" id="ctl00_SwitchLoginScreenModeBT" class="btn" /> 
</div>

<input name="ctl00$HiddenValue" type="hidden" id="ctl00_HiddenValue" value="Initial Value" />
<input name="ctl00$HiddenValue2" type="hidden" id="ctl00_HiddenValue2" value="Initial Value" />
```

Comment: Your `data` is ill-formed, it should be more like this instead: `"ctl00%24LoginTextBox=USERNAME&ctl00%24PasswordTextbox=PASSWORD&ctl00%24LogInButton=Sign+in&ctl00%24HiddenValue=Initial+Value"`. Don't forget to encode `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` if they contain non-ASCII/reserved characters.  In fact, you can (and should) use [`curl_easy_escape()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) to properly encode every `name` and `value` component of every `name=value` pair that you are posting.

Comment: Also, what does the `<form>` tag actually look like in the HTML? In particular, what is its `enctype` attribute set to? Does it submit the webform to the server using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type (the default if no `enctype` is specified), or the `multipart/form-data` media type? It makes a BIG difference, because `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` uses the former, but some servers use the latter instead, in which case you would have to use [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html) instead.

Comment: <form name="TransactionPage" method="post" action="TransactionPage.aspx?TabID=0" id="TransactionPage" enctype="multipart/form-data">  So I guess I have to change that too. Thanks!

Comment: See `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. So you are indeed posting the webform data the wrong way when using [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html). You need to use [`curl_formadd()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) with [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html), or use [`curl_mime_init()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_init.html) and [`curl_mime_addpart()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_addpart.html) with [`CURLOPT_MIMEPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.html).

Comment: How would I use this curl_formadd() function in my case?

Comment: There are examples in the [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html) and [`curl_formadd()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) documentations. Did you read them yet? <Sigh> Hold on, I will write up an answer for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- Your `data` is not properly url-encoded completely.  You can (and should) use [`curl_easy_escape()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) to properly encode every `name` and `value` component of every `name=value` pair that you post with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.
- You are posting `data` using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, which posts in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (which is the default for many webforms online), but the particular webform in question is actually expecting `data` to be posted in `multipart/form-data` format instead (due to the webform's `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute), so you need to use [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html) (deprecated) or [`CURLOPT_MIMEPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.html) instead.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *myHandle = curl_easy_init();

    // Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

    // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "website login page URL here");
    curl_easy_perform(myHandle);

    // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "website login page URL here");

    // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
    struct curl_httppost *data = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *last = NULL;

    curl_formadd(&data, &last, CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "ctl00$LoginTextBox", CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, "USERNAME", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&data, &last, CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "ctl00$PasswordTextbox", CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, "PASSWORD", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&data, &last, CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "ctl00$LogInButton", CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, "Sign in", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&data, &last, CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "ctl00$HiddenValue", CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, "Initial Value", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, data);

    curl_easy_perform(myHandle);

    curl_formfree(data);
    curl_easy_cleanup(myHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Or this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *myHandle = curl_easy_init();

    // Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

    // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "website login page URL here");
    curl_easy_perform(myHandle);

    // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "website login page URL here");

    // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
    curl_mime *mime = curl_mime_init(myHandle);

    curl_mimepart *part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
    curl_mime_name(part, "ctl00$LoginTextBox");
    curl_mime_data(part, "USERNAME", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

    part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
    curl_mime_name(part, "ctl00$PasswordTextbox");
    curl_mime_data(part, "PASSWORD", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

    part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
    curl_mime_name(part, "ctl00$LogInButton");
    curl_mime_data(part, "Sign in", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

    part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
    curl_mime_name(part, "ctl00$HiddenValue");
    curl_mime_data(part, "Initial Value", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, data);

    curl_easy_perform(myHandle);

    curl_mime_free(mime);
    curl_easy_cleanup(myHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still cannot get past the login stage, but I really appreciate all your help thus far!

Comment: Then I suggest you use your browser's built-in debugger to log EXACTLY what the browser is submitting to the server at every step, and use [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to log EXACTLY what libcurl is submitting at each step, and then you can compare the two outputs and adjust your libcurl usage as needed.

Comment: Ok, so I tried using the chrome dev tools to look at the get and post requests and responses.

Comment: @AudreyEagle and? what did you find?

Comment: My guess it went nowhere. And it’s a very poor implementation, also lacks receiving data via a write back function so receiving end is handled how exactly?